# ¿Es posible construir un objeto de una clase o declarar una variable directamente en el retorno de un metodo?

Tags: c#

Supongamos que tengo este metodo...

```
    private BigInteger Numero(string cadena)
            {
               if (CadenaConValor(cadena) != 0 && CadenaOk(cadena))
               {
                   BigInteger n;
                   return n = BigInteger.Parse(cadena);
               }
               return 0;
            }
```

¿Podría en el return simplificar la sintaxis para devolver directamente el string `cadena` convertido, sin tener que crear la variable `n` en la linea anterior?

Como expongo en el titulo, también me sucede cuando intento devolver objetos los cuales tengo que instanciarlos antes de poder devolverlos.

Comment: Intentas que sea una funcion recursiva?

Comment: No, es simplemente el poder hacerlo directamente en el propio return para no tener la necesidad de crear la variable "n", y hacerlo todo "al vuelo"

Comment: Tienes una buena respuesta. Igual la creacion de la variable esta de mas, porque en la linea siguiente la asignacion no tiene ningun sentido ya que esta en la misma linea que el return.. en tu caso, para que el codigo solamente estuviera "muy legible" tendrias que haber hecho: BigInteger n;n = BigInteger.Parse(cadena);return n;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro. Simplemente eliminas la asignacion y retornas el valor de retorno del metodo `BigInteger.Parse`:

```
 private BigInteger Numero(string cadena)
{
   if (CadenaConValor(cadena) != 0 && CadenaOk(cadena))
   {
       return  BigInteger.Parse(cadena);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Y utilizando un operador ternario puedes simplificar el codigo aun mas:

```
 private BigInteger Numero(string cadena)
{

   return (CadenaConValor(cadena) != 0 && CadenaOk(cadena)) ?  BigInteger.Parse(cadena) : 0;
}
```